# Nokia Qt in-app purchase testing on multiple device for same user

Tags: qt, resolve

I have integrated the QT API for Nokia OVI store in-app purchase i.e. IAPClient.

The reference to the IAPClient is [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Qt_IAP/_zip/GUID-532F510B-9EE3-4069-AD8D-3E225C47A446/class_i_a_p_client.html)

I am able to purchase items and restore them successfully on one device (the Nokia E7) using user credentials (my_username_to_OVI : my_password_to_OVI) to OVI store.

Is it possible to restore the same items (which I already have purchased on one Nokia device) on another Nokia device using the same credentials to OVI store?

> It has been confirmed by Nokia Customer Care that we have to purchase the items on different devices even-if we use same username:password to OVI store. Those items will not be restorable on different devices until we pay for them.